# Convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,TopTerminalsDTO>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to return JSON from Rest API endpoint as keys with values from DB table with data. Example:

```
  {
    "terminal 1":
       {"date":"2018-10-06T00:00:00.000+0000","volume":111,"count":1},
    "terminal 2":
       {"date":"2018-11-06T00:00:00.000+0000","volume":122,"count":1}
  }
```

I tried to convert the result from DB by getting the table column `terminal` and setting it as key. But I get error

```
@GetMapping("/terminals")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, TopTerminalsDTO>> getTopTerminalsVolumes(
            @RequestParam(value = "start_date", required = true) String start_date,
            @RequestParam(value = "end_date", required = true) String end_date) {

            LocalDateTime start_datel = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
            LocalDateTime end_datel = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());

            final List<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> list = dashboardRepository.top_daily_transactions(start_datel, end_datel);

            final Map<String, TopTerminalsDTO> map =
                        list.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(dto -> dto.getTerminal(), dto -> dto));



        return ResponseEntity.ok(map);
    }
```

Do you know how I can solve the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,TopTerminalsDTO>`?

Comment: What is the type of terminal in PaymentTransactionDailyFacts?

Comment: It's a Integer value.

Comment: Then how can you map integer to string?, do like this dto-> "terminal"+dto.getTerminal();

Comment: Also, you seem to be implicitly converting a `PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts` to a `TopTerminalsDTO`.  This seems dodgy to me.

Comment: final Map<String, TopTerminalsDTO> map =
                        list.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(dto -> dto.getTerminal(), dto -> (TopTerminalsDTO)dto));